# setContentView execute too late

Tags: android

I have a problem, I make a simple application to show you my problem.
I want that setContentView executes and displays the .xml BEFORE the Sleep is executed. I thought everything will be execute in order? 
Is there anyone how can say me why it doesn't do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // do something
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Here is the real OnCreate, seems to be a bigger problem.

Everything with the sleep worked fine, but with the Connect method there are problems.

*public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*

```
ConnectBluetooth();

}
```

In the ConnectBluetooth() method, I just create a new Socket and try a connection.

With a ned thread or a handler it doesn't seems to work, what should I do then? Use something like an asynctask?

Thanks a lot in common!

Comment: IMO `sleep(...)` is a hack in any programming language on any platform but you're really asking for trouble if you use it in Android (especially on the main/UI thread).

Answer (score 2):

The layout isn't displayed until after the creation process has finished, after `onResume()` is called. However there is no callback for when the layout is displayed, but you can use a Handler and Runnable to do this.

---

Create a couple field variables:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something 
    }
};
```

And `onCreate()` call:

```
handler.postDelayed(delay, 10000);
```

Comment: 100? Shouldn't that be 10000? ;)

Comment: Yes. I was confused on what the OP was trying to do, for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sleep`, you are pausing the UI thread. This will prevent `onCreate` from returning, which will prevent the framework from completing initialization of your activity, including displaying your view hierarchy.

You should never pause the UI thread like that. If you want to do something after 10 seconds, you can start a separate thread that will do it at the right time:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                doSomething();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

A cleaner approach would be to use a `Handler`:

```
Handler mHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doSomething();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: "You should never pause the UI thread like that." An upvote for this sentence alone but also for having the same basic answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! My problem was, that I didn't know, that the oncreate has to finish bevor the content of the xml will be displayed!
I only made this little program with sleep to show you what I mean, my program has a Bluetoothconnect to call, and this needs some time, but I didn't want to post this long program.

Comment: @user1927295 - Making a Bluetooth call, doing network activity--even accessing the file system on the device--should be done off the UI thread. On recent Android versions, just attempting to perform network activity on the UI thread will raise an exception.